# how to set ringtones for the second sim card

Tags: android, ringtone, sim-card

Do anybody know how to set ringtones for the second sim card on android mobile,like samsung W899 device~

```
RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(Media_RingTongActivity.this, RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM, pickedUri);
```

this just set the first sim card, how to do for the second, thanks~

Comment: Hi, @iceskysl have you got any answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set a ringtone for the second SIM card using Android API.

The Android platform doesn't have support for multiple SIM cards. All devices supporting more SIM cards are running versions of the Android OS that were customized by the manufacturers.

Answer (score 0):

I tested two ways of doing it on my Samsung S20. Some of them may not work on your phone:

1. Replace file with another. This is the most versatile approach, because it allows not only changing sound for second SIM, but also allows to change sound for any application. What you need to do is first set sound to some particular file manually and then copy another file over it (for example using Tasker). For example, create whatsapp.wav file and copy any mp3, ogg, or wav file over it. Macrodroid seems to not be able to copy a single file to a new name like this.
2. Change ringtone, ringtone_2, notification_sound or notification_sound_2 (to change first SIM ringtone, second SIM ringtone, first SIM SMS, second SIM SMS) in Macrodroid - System Setting. You can change it to string like `file:///sdcard/Notifications/myfile.wav` for example.